# Erro SQLSTATE[HY000] [1105] (proxy) all backends are down (SQL: select * from `users` where `id` = 1 limit 1) laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tenho um site desenvolvido em Laravel 5.8, coloquei no ar, e quando estou navegando pelo site recebo este erro: `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1105] (proxy) all backends are down (SQL: select * from`users`where`id`= 1 limit 1).`

Porém, esse erro aparece do nada, as vezes quando vou para uma outra página, ou quando volto a página no navegador.

Alguém pode me dar uma dica do que posso fazer pra não acontecer mais?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso parece um problema de direcionamento de IP no servidor. Se for a primeira vez que você subiu, verifique os direcionamentos nas configurações do seu servidor e se o seu domínio está apontando corretamente para o servidor onde está o seu BD.